# TextView doesn't show the message, NSLog does

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to send and return data from a server. I'm sure that the data are available because I can print them out in Target Output using NSLog in ResultsViewController.m, but using TextView I can't.

here is the code:

ResultsViewController.h

```
@interface ResultsViewController : UIViewController <ServiceConnectorDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
{}

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *output;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *value1TextView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *value1TextField;

- (void)sendString:(NSString *)str;

@end
```

ResultsViewController.m

```
- (void)sendString:(NSString *)str
{ 
    ServiceConnector *serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [serviceConnector getTest: str];
}


- (void)requestReturnedData:(NSData *)data //called when data is returned
{ 
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];
    output.text = dictionary.JSONString; // set the textview to the raw string value of the data received

    value1TextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[dictionary objectForKey:@"value"] intValue]];
    value1TextField.text = @"test";
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
```

ServiceConnector.m

```
@implementation ServiceConnector
{
    NSData *receivedData;
}

- (void)getTest:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *storedURL = str;
    NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",storedURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"getValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"]; //selects what task the server will perform

    //initialize an NSURLConnection  with the request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

Probably there is a problem with TextView because it doesn't respond to such a simple code:

```
value1TextField.text = @"test";
```

To connect the app to the server I use a delegate of Service Connector, but I'm not sure that I have implemented the delegate in the right way. Especially when I define

```
serviceConnector.delegate = self;
```

In another app I implement the delegate using a Button and it works:

```
- (IBAction)getDown:(id)sender 
{
    //perform get request
    ServiceConnector *serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [serviceConnector getTest];
}
```

Comment: Is the textfield outlet connected to the .xib?

Comment: If your text view does not show "test", why are you posting your code for server retrieval?

Comment: Yes, I connected it to the File'Owner

Comment: test if your value1TextField is nil if not, test its frame, else test if it has a superview.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I've done a check with a "if (value1TextField.text == nil)" and it is actually nil, what do you suggest?

Comment: what is the size of the `UITextField`? what is a colour of the text? what is background colour of the `UITextField`? it is at the top of the view hierarchy?

Comment: 97x30, black, white, and yes it's in the view controller's view.

Comment: other ideas? Could it be that when I was using the GetDown method it was changing in some way the hierarchy of the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *output;
```

should be a `strong` property like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *output;
```

Also, make sure to use property accessors like this:

```
self.value1TextField.text = @"test";
```

And make sure your `File Owner` is `ResultsViewController` and that it is connected in the .xib

Comment: Thanks Ralfonso, I've made the changes and I've also checked the connection. But it doesn't work. File Owner it's actually a class of ResultsViewController, but not sure that it's connected to .xib. I'm going to search how to do that.

Comment: By 'make sure its connected in the .xib', I mean to make sure you have your IBOutlets connected to their associated UIView components in Interface Builder.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this line: `self.value1TextField.text = @"test";` And verify that `value1TextField` isn't nil

Comment: Ah, ok.. Then it is connected. Everything works fine if instead of defining the delegate in the sendString method I do it in the getDown one. So the connection are fine.

Comment: Done. The output is nil, value1TextField.text as well and data contain some bits. What should I look for?

Comment: If value1TextField is nil, then your IBOutlets aren't connected or there is some other issue related to your ResultsViewController in Interface Builder.

Comment: Are you sure your text color in XIB isn't set to white or some other colors that is the same as the color of your background? :D
Happened to me today

Comment: no it not that... unfortunately! Would have been easy to solve. Thanks anyway

Comment: Try giving the value1TextField a default value in IB. If you can't see it when ResultsViewController is loaded, then value1TextField is not being initialized properly.

Comment: If I set a value in xib file, the when a run the application I can see it on the screen.